# OS choice for JBoss AS installation in a Windows Server 2008 environment

Tags: java, windows, deployment, windows-7, jboss

To avoid installation of client access licenses for another Windows 2008 Server in a W2K8 environment, the administrator offered me to install a Windows 7 VM installation where I could install some JBoss 6 AS web applications.

However I think there might be disadvantages of using Windows 7 (resource usage, integration with the other servers). Would Windows Web Server 2008 be a better option? It does not require CALs for the web users and would have a similar configuration user interface.

Update: the server is meant to be used for a production environment of a low traffic Internet web application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear, are you talking about using Windows 7 for a web application dedicated to production or to development?

If you need to access your web application in a production environment I believe that the license of Windows 7 prohibits this, if you need a development or testing environment then Windows 7 could be OK. Windows 7 also has some limitation in the tcpip stack, I believe.

Regards
Massimo

Comment: Thank your for pointing out the license issue - Windows 7 only has single user licenses - strange that the admin did not know this.